# ¿Cómo puedo trabajar con websockets (PHP) en un hosting web externo?

Tags: php, web, hosting, websocket

He elaborado una aplicación web con PHP la cual hace uso de websockets. Esto también fue hecho con PHP. La aplicación funciona en un entorno local (WAMP) en donde varios usuarios acceden a la aplicación desde sus terminales de trabajo, y es a partir de las distintas acciones que estos efectúan que los websockets lanzan notificaciones en tiempo real. Para hacer funcionar los websockets, solamente tengo que ejecutar la siguiente línea desde el CMD:

```
C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.2.10\php.exe -q C:\wamp64\www\myapp\websocket_daemon.php
```

El caso es que ahora necesito hacer funcionar esto en una aplicación web alojada en un hosting web externo, al cual solamente tengo acceso a través del CPanel y FTP. Entonces, mi pregunta es, ¿cómo puedo trabajar con los websockets en un hosting web externo?

Comment: dale un vistazo a la función `shell_exec()`  o  `exec()` . No se que hosting estas utilizando  y si tienes una maquina compartida.  dependiendo que compañia te dejan ejecutar comandos de consola o no.

Comment: Tambien podrias Utilizar un crome job que ejeute el script  `websocket_daemon.php`